# Is there a purpose behind making a private method static?

Tags: .net, static

To my understanding, the only purpose of static is to enable a method to be called on the class itself, not an instance of it. But if the method is also private, you'll only be able to call it from within the class. So, is there a reason to declare something as both private and static? ReSharper recommends I make many of my methods static and I just don't see the point for the private ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have  a (`public` or whatever) `static` method in the class and this method needs to use your `private` method. That doesn't work if it's not `static`.

```
public static void Foo1()
{
    Foo2(); // compile time error
}

private void Foo2()
{

}
```

Methods need to be instance methods only if they need to use fields or properties that are not static (among other reasons like inheritance). Therefore it's best practice to make it static.

Comment: While I'd say everyone answered my question, this seems like the most practical reason to make a private method static so I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Performance.  It is a (micro) optimization.
The CLR needs to perform less steps to find the method that he needs to execute.

For a detailed explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

> A call to a static method generates a call instruction in Microsoft
>   intermediate language (MSIL), whereas a call to an instance method
>   generates a callvirt instruction, which also checks for a null object
>   references. However, most of the time the performance difference
>   between the two is not significant.

Answer (score 1):

If your private method doesn't uses any *instance methods or fields or properties* then it is good to mark it as static.

Doing so, you get `call` opcode emitted in IL which will not perform any "null checking" before calling the method. where as instance methods emits `callvirt` opcode which does that "null checking" before calling the method. This helps you to get performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You tend to see this if a method has been written that doesn't use the state of the object and is an implementation detail. You could just make it `private`, but some people prefer to make it `static` as well to fully indicate that the method doesn't touch the state.

Personally I'd just go with the `private`.